# what is the difference between ssh-add and ssh-keygen

Tags: ssh

I know ssh-keygen it can create a public and private key inside `~/.ssh` by default as `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`

eg:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Later on we add the `id_rsa.pub` to the `known_hosts` of the server, so that we can do

```
ssh user@hostname.com
```

But I see we use `ssh-add` to pass private key so that we can login without the need of password

Eg:

```
ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
```

for this we need to start ssh-agent

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

and then

```
ssh user@hostname.com
```

Assuming there is already `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. So here how does ssh know which private key it has to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh`, if it finds a value for `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in the environment, will ask that agent for *all* private keys and try them one by one, unless you tell it which specific key to use via the `-i` command-line option or the `IdentitiyFile` configuration option.

The main benefit of `ssh-agent` is that it can hold *unencrypted* keys in memory, so that you only need to use the key's passphrase once, when it is added to the agent, rather than every time `ssh` tries to use the key.

(The other benefit is that if you have multiple `ssh` connections in a chain, you can keep the private keys in an agent on the first machine. The `ssh` client can forward the agent connection to the remote machine, where `ssh` clients can access the agent to use keys for the next step in the chain.)

Comment: so it will go through all the keys. Thats how it checks